# Dynamically set the layout parameters of a relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I need help to dynamically change the layout parameters of a layout that already exists in the xml with some pre defined values for layout_width and layout_height . I want to give these some new values dynamically in my java code . i am using the following code but i get an error and don;t know how to proceed . please help

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.CompLayout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(10,10);
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Please help !!!!

Comment: The Force close error .... No exception as i have handles all exceptions ...

Comment: If you get a force close, then an exception has been thrown. Whatever way you handle it, it will appear in the LogCat. Please post it here and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

xml is define as

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff"></RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

and code is

```
     RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 50);
            layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: R u sure this works because in my case the relative layout is within a linear layout but otherwise everything is the same but it doesn't seem to work ...